# Formating Div by width of image inside it

Tags: css

How do i set the table under the images to be the same width as the image above? Thanks for your help!

http://cran-web.com/letaky/generate/10

EDIT: I was talking about "tab_cena", not "tab_objednavky". Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Nazdar!)

There are only 2 kinds of measurements you can give the table: a fixed width like `1000px`, or a percentage like `100%`. If you give a fixed width, then you have to know the width of the items above (4 cells, 249px each). If you give a percentage, then it depends on the size of the element that contains your table.

You can use a percentage to your advantage. Since your table is in a 249px cell and you want it to stretch across 4 cells, try setting the width to `400%`. It's a little bit of a hack because you're breaking out of the cell container, but it should work.

A better way would be to make the `.cell` equal 249px x 4 (`996px`), and just make the `#tab_objednavky` table inside it `100%` width.

Edit: to answer your question based on the title of your post: you can't do that without using JavaScript to set the size of the container div.

Comment: The only way to do that without JavaScript I found is to set the div to float, but it works only if I float right or left - and I need it in center. 
'code'
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#THIS DIV').width($('#cell_img_0_0').width());
});

This code should work, but doesn't. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of your table (#tab_objednavky) to 100%.

Currently your style shows that you have the width of your table set to 160%.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I am fully understanding, but `#tab_objednavky` style you have `width: 160%`. Just set that to `width: 100%` and it will fill the `.cell` container.

Comment: The empty table is OK, I was talking about table under each image with "Naše cena 249,- Kč etc." Sorry for this misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your layout it looks like the width of the image containers is set by the class `.cell_1`, so just add it to your table and you should set. (Actually you should replace the existing `cell` class that is already applied to it.)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just place the image as the first row of the table?